# How to check if my account already in chat, channel, private channel, private group?

Tags: telethon

I want to check if my account is member of the channel. How can I do this if I only have valid invite link

Answer (score 0):

With the current telethon API, you can't check if you're a member of a channel or private group using an invite link. However, you can resolve the invite link into channel ID and then use [iter_dialogs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs) to check if there is a same ID.

To avoid `FloodWait`, it's better to do `iter_dialogs` once and save a local copy for yourself. You may update your local copy when you join new channels and groups.

For public groups you can [iter_participants](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants) and find yourself. However, the former method still works here as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```py
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        if dialog.entity.megagroup:
            group_name = dialog.entity.title
            members_count = str(dialog.entity.participants_count)
            print(f'GROUP: {group_name} - ({members_count} members)')
```

Here I checked if the chat is a [megagroup](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/chats-vs-channels.html), if so then it will print participants count and group's name.